# Error API Shodan Error: Access denied (403 Forbidden)

Tags: python, shodan

When i try to scan an ip, always throes the same error, (Error: Access denied (403 Forbidden))

```
def getShodan(ip):
    print("-------Shodan-------")
    
    try:
        api = shodan.Shodan("")
        info = api.host(ip)
        return ("""
                IP: {}
                HOSTNAMES: {}
                COUNTRYNAME: {}
                PORTS: {}
                ORGANIZATION: {}
                OPERATINGSYSTEM: {}
                """.format(ip, info.get('hostnames'), info.get('country_name'), info.get('ports'), info.get('org'), info.get('os')))
    except shodan.exception.APIError as e:
        print(('Error:')+' %s\n---------------------------------\n\n' % e)
        exit(0)
```

I already change the API key multiple times but nothing changes

Comment: that seems like an invalid api key ... can you do their curl example for `/host/{ip}` and that works?

Comment: How i can do that, im new with API and web stuff

Comment: Also get this Error message when i try to check mi key                                              401 Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.

Comment: if you go to their docs ... they have a bunch of examples of how to call the endpoints with curl ... maybe get that working first (it should be equivelent ... but sometimes having a copy paste example is a helpful place to start)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error, and realized I had accidentally signed into a new account. You do not get access to the API by default. If you sign up with a University email, they should automatically give you the academic upgrade. Otherwise you have to pay for API services.